# Discrete convexity and greedy algorithm

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, discrete-optimization

Suppose that $f(x_1, x_2, ... x_K)$ is convex nonincreasing, and we only consider its values for integer $x_1, x_2, ..., x_K$. Furthermore, consider the problem:
\begin{align}
\min_{x_k \in \mathbb{Z}^+} & \, f(x_1, x_2, ..., x_K) \\
\text{s.t. }  &\sum_{k=1}^K x_k = B \\
&x_k \le b_k, \, \, k = 1, ..., K.
\end{align}
Would a simple greedy algorithm be guaranteed to find the optimal solution to this problem? Any comments and references are very much appreciated.

Greedy algorithm: Start at the point where $x_k = 0$ for all $k$; Increase by 1 the $x_k$ that would result in the greatest improvement in the objective; Repeat the previous step (without violating the last constraint) until we use up the budget B.

Comment: How does your greedy algorithm handle ties?  In other words, if the current iterate is $x$ and you have two directions $p$ and $q$, what does greedy do if $f(x+p)=f(x+q)$?

Comment: Many thanks for the great question. I haven't had ties in my numerical examples. That said, now I see how the greedy algorithm could get trapped in a local minima: for example, if after a tie, we move in the direction in which the function flattens out more quickly. A related question: Would having no ties during the search be a sufficient condition for the greedy to find the optimal solution? Thanks again.

Comment: It certainly works if you can write $f(x_1, ..., x_K) = f(x_1) + ... + f(x_K)$. So maybe you can construct a counterexample that cannot be decomposed in this way, idk...